# Share closure code (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to share code between two closures?

Example:

```
// ANTIPATTERN

var cbDoThing = function cbDoThing(arg){
    return typeof closed1 +" " + arg;
}

function getClosure1(closed1) {
    return cbDoThing;
}

function getClosure2(closed1) {
    return function(arg) {
        // do other work
        return cbDoThing(arg);
    }
}

f1 = getClosure1();
f1("ARG1"); // returns "undefined ARG1"
f2 = getClosure2();
f2("ARG2"); // returns "undefined ARG2"
```

Here `getClosure1()` and `getClosure2()` return a closure that does similar tasks. I.e. both of them need to execute the `cbDoThing()` within a closure environment, but `getClosure2()` runs some other code in addition.

The above example does not work as wanted. `cbDoThing()` is defined in the global context, so closed1 variable is undefined. The wanted behavior is a pattern to make the closed1 variable be read from the closure scope chain, but without redefining the `cbDoThing()`function in each closure.

PS: [JsFiddle playground](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZUpW/1/).

**EDIT**: 
Now that I asked, an answer came to me with minor modifications:

```
var cbDoThing = function cbDoThing(closed1, arg){
    return closed1 +" " + arg;
}

function getClosure1(closed1) {
    return function(arg) {
        return cbDoThing(closed1, arg);            
    }
}

function getClosure2(closed1) {
    return function(arg) {
        // do other work
        return cbDoThing(closed1, arg);
    }
}
```

The cbDoThing does not access closed1 variable from the closure variable scope. Rather it is passed an extra argument. Then this function is called from each of the closures.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZUpW/1/)

Comment: That's it (since that is not way to get the closed1 from the caller closure)!

Answer (score 2):

Nice work.  Javascript only walks down the prototypal chain, which means that cbDoThing has no reference or declaration of closed1.  In this case, cbDoThing has only one prototype - Object.  Without explicitly passing an argument to cbDoThing, it will not have any notion of the closed1.

Here is a thorough discussion of closures in javascript: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/